# How to change axis linewidth and fontsize in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, axes

I am trying to resize some plots in Octave. I've been able to change the line thickness and axis labels. However, I cannot find a way to make the axes themselves thicker, or the numbers larger.

What I've found online uses set(), like

```
plot(x, y, "linewidth",5);
h=get(gcf, "currentaxes");
set(h, "fontsize", 12, "linewidth", 2);
```

or

```
set(gca, 'linewidth', 4);
```

But, I am continuing to see the errors

```
invalid property 'linewidth'
invalid property 'fontsize'
```

even though they are listed as properties in the [Octave documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axes-Properties.html#Axes-Properties)

What am I doing wrong?

Or, what else can I try?

Answer (score 35):

With octave 3.8.2 it is working fine.

```
x=1:10;
plot(x, x, "linewidth", 5)
set(gca, "linewidth", 4, "fontsize", 12)
```

yields
[image: working linewidth]

as it should

Comment: I have octave 3.0.5. Could an outdated version be the issue?

Comment: @qstnhr probably. Your link to the documentation is to the latest Octave version but you are using a very much old version. Check on the documentation of the version you have installed for the correct option names (the Octave manual is part of an Octave installation).

Comment: It should be added that using `linewidth` in the *`plot()`* function sets that line width, whereas if you use it in the *`set(gca,...)`*, you will set all lines, like border etc.